# How do I claim a URL for Facebook Instant Articles

Tags: facebook-instant-articles

When I try to claim my URL I get this error:

`The fb:pages tag on the url doesn't contain this page's id. The url has
fb:pages tag but they don't have this page's id. Please work with your
developers / webmaster to add this tag to your website.`

Am I supposed to place this meta tag: `<meta property="fb:pages" content="130810137587****" />` in the head of my web page's HTML before I can calm my URL? Or in the head of my Instant Article's HTML
?

Answer (score 3):

You place that meta tag in the html for the url/subdomain/path you are trying to claim. Not in the instant articles.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Wordpress add your meta tag in the header.php file in the `<HEAD>...</HEAD>` section

Answer (score 0):

You must put the tag between the  tags of your website in the index

```
<Head>
     <Meta property = "fb: pages" content = "130810137587 ****" />
</ Head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably also need to update the open graph 'type' property:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

As is said here:
https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=10156960334050657

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is trying to read the metadata from your canonical URL, you can check which URL it's using on their debugging tool:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Paste your URL and check the Canonical URL info and its headers, that's the domain you need to update with the meta tag .

In my case, it was pointing to a different URL in my test environment.

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

I have the same error.
you need to add the **meta tag** inside **Head tag**.
 of your website.